# Commit SQL even inside atomic transaction (django)

Tags: django, transactions, atomic

How can I always commit a insert even inside an atomic transaction? In this case I need just one point to be committed and everything else rolled back.

For example, my view, decorator contains `with transaction.atomic()` and other stuffs:

```
@my_custom_decorator_with_transaction_atomic
def my_view(request):
    my_core_function()
    return ...
```

```
def my_core_function():
    # many sql operations that need to rollback in case of error

    try:
        another_operation()
    except MyException:
        insert_activity_register_on_db() # This needs to be in DB, and not rolled back
        raise MyException()
```

I would not like to make another decorator for my view without transaction atomic and do it manually on core. Is there a way?